# Java util.Date usage

Tags: java, date

I wanted to use the `util.Date` class in *Java*, but when I tried to instantiate a `Date` object, I realized that all the constructors that I can understand--the simple ones--were gone. All deprecated.

Can anybody tell me how I can make use of `Date` class?

Here is my code.

Constructor:

```
public Company(int id, String name, Date foundationDate) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.foundationDate = foundationDate;
}
```

TestClass:

```
Company[] companies = new Company[3];
companies[0] = new Company(1, "Sabanci", new Date(12,12,12));
```

Comment: Ideally, don't; use JODA Time instead.

Comment: Every deprecated method has an explanation for the deprecation, explaining what to use instead. Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This constructor has been deprecated since Java 1.1 ([a long time ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.1_.28February_19.2C_1997.29))  From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

> Date(int year, int month, int date)
>
> Deprecated.
>
> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by [Calendar.set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29)(year + 1900, month, date) or [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29)(year + 1900, month, date).

As for the vastly superior [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) approach (from [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)):

```
new DateTime(2012,12,12,0,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use standard Java classes and you want to avoid deprecated methods (which is a good idea), then you can use the `java.util.Calendar` class. As stated in the comments, the JODA Time library is much easier to use, but `Calendar` is built in.

To create the Date December 12, 2012:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(2012, Calendar.DECEMBER, 12);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

You end up with a `java.util.Date`. Obviously, you can create a convenience method to build the `Calendar` object and just return the `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 1.8 you can now also use the standard `time` library.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 12 , 12 );  // ( year , month , day-of-month )
```

Or parse a String.

```
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.parse("2012-12-12");
```